# XPath to Get Value from Sibling with Namespace

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following xml doc:

```
<GetGeneralServiceRequestByReferenceValueResponse xmlns="http://www.caps-solutions.co.uk/webservices/connectors/731/servicerequest/messagetypes">
    <GeneralServiceRequest xmlns="http://www.caps-solutions.co.uk/schema/uniform/731/servicerequest/sr/srtypes">
        <ServiceRequestIdentification>
            <ServiceRequestTechnicalKey>PG7ECIJBKFX00</ServiceRequestTechnicalKey>
            <ReferenceValue>18/009969/S_SCBC</ReferenceValue>
            <AlternativeReferences>
                <AlternativeReference xmlns="http://www.caps-solutions.co.uk/schema/uniform/72b/common/uniformtypes">
                    <ReferenceValue>W44811182451</ReferenceValue>
                    <ReferenceType>UTRN</ReferenceType>
                </AlternativeReference>
                <AlternativeReference xmlns="http://www.caps-solutions.co.uk/schema/uniform/72b/common/uniformtypes">
                    <ReferenceValue>00482</ReferenceValue>
                    <ReferenceType>BAD</ReferenceType>
                </AlternativeReference>
            </AlternativeReferences>
            <SiteID>JB</SiteID>
        </ServiceRequestIdentification>
    </GeneralServiceRequest>
</GetGeneralServiceRequestByReferenceValueResponse>
```

I need to select the `<ReferenceValue>` that has a sibling `<ReferenceType>` of "UTRN"

The following xpath get's me the `<ReferenceValue>` of the last `<Alternative>` reference.

```
/*[local-name()='GetGeneralServiceRequestByReferenceValueResponse']/*[local-name()='GeneralServiceRequest']/*[local-name()='ServiceRequestIdentification']/*[local-name()='AlternativeReferences']/*[local-name()='AlternativeReference']/*[local-name()='ReferenceValue']
```

I've tried using [] for the parent AlternativeReference node then ReferenceValue='UTRN' but haven't been able to get the required output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `local-name()`. Declare the namespaces in your XSLT and use the prefixes.

For example, declare them like this (you can pick any prefixes you like, as long as the namespace URIs match):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msg="http://www.caps-solutions.co.uk/webservices/connectors/731/servicerequest/messagetypes"
  xmlns:sr="http://www.caps-solutions.co.uk/schema/uniform/731/servicerequest/sr/srtypes"
  xmlns:uni="http://www.caps-solutions.co.uk/schema/uniform/72b/common/uniformtypes"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msg sr uni"
>
```

And use (wrapped for legibility, but XPath is not whitespace-sensitive, you can wrap it the same way in your XSLT):

```
/msg:GetGeneralServiceRequestByReferenceValueResponse
/sr:GeneralServiceRequest
/sr:ServiceRequestIdentification
/sr:AlternativeReferences
/uni:AlternativeReference[uni:ReferenceType = 'UTRN']
/uni:ReferenceValue
```

Here, `/uni:AlternativeReference[uni:ReferenceType = 'UTRN']` only selects those `<AlternativeReference>` nodes who have a `<ReferenceType>` child of the wanted value.

---

Since there are many ways to look at an XML tree (and because I think that explicitly. naming. every. single. step. along. the. way. is overdoing it), something like this would also work:

```
//uni:ReferenceType[. = 'UTRN']/../uni:ReferenceValue
```

or

```
//uni:AlternativeReference[uni:ReferenceType = 'UTRN']/uni:ReferenceValue
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add criteria to the `<AlternativeReference>` predicate to restrict the selection of `<AlternativeReference>` elements to those that have a `<ReferenceType>` element who's value is "UTRN":

```
/*[local-name()='GetGeneralServiceRequestByReferenceValueResponse']/
  *[local-name()='GeneralServiceRequest']/
    *[local-name()='ServiceRequestIdentification']/
      *[local-name()='AlternativeReferences']/
        *[local-name()='AlternativeReference' and *[local-name()='ReferenceType' and .='UTRN']]/
          *[local-name()='ReferenceValue']
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
"//AlternativeReference[1]/ReferenceValue"
```

Or if you know the sibling value:

```
"//ReferenceType[text()='UTRN']/parent::*/ReferenceValue"
```